# Can trinidad (running as a daemon) cope with multiple versions of rails (and rack)?

Tags: deployment, jruby, bundler, trinidad-gem

Forgive me if this is a silly question!

But to run trinidad as a daemon does it need to be in the system gems?
Or can you install just the daemon extension to the system gems?

If the former is true is it still possible to run different versions of rails?
My thinking is that `Trinidad` requires `JRuby-Rack` which requires `Rack` and naturally each version of `Rails` uses a differen version of `Rack`!

To put this into context i am considering using bundler's `--deployment` option to manage different versions of gems for each application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up emailing David Calavera (the project lead) about this.

**TL;DR** Yes ya can!

Here's his response:

Yes, you can. Trinidad uses different runtimes for each application, what in other servers is called "workers", and so each application runs in its own isolated jruby runtime.

Check the wiki to know how to load your apps:

https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad/wiki/advanced-configuration